# Azure VM password stops working and must be reset

Tags: azure

Azure VM password works one day and then the next day it does not. I had to reset password in a couple of VMs this way to login in again. Is this a bug in azure? How to prevent this?

Comment: I'm guessing the password has to be changed every X days ? check the password policy of your user.

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the your password policy configuration setting, Your password is expiring after every 24 hr.

Password expiry duration Default value is: 90 days

The value is configurable by using the **Set-MsolPasswordPolicy** cmdlet from the Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell.

**Set password policies by using PowerShell**

To get started,  [download and install the Azure AD PowerShell module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Azuread/) and  [connect it to your Azure AD tenant.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/connect-azuread#examples)

After the module is installed, use the following steps to set password policy.

**Set a password to never expire**

1. Open a PowerShell prompt and [connect to your Azure AD tenant](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/connect-azuread#examples)using a global
   administrator or user administrator account.
2. Run one of the following commands for either an individual user or for all users

• To set the password of one user to never expire, run the following cmdlet.
Replace `<user ID>` with the user ID of the user you want to check, such as
driley@contoso.onmicrosoft.com

> **Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId  -PasswordPolicies DisablePasswordExpiration**

•To set the passwords of all the users in an organization to never expire, run
the following cmdlet:

> **Get-AzureADUser -All $true | Set-AzureADUser -PasswordPolicies DisablePasswordExpiration**

Here is the Microsoft Document which you can refer to : [Password policies and account restrictions in Azure Active Directory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-policy)